# ST_Union or ST_Collect on PostgreSQL union result?

Tags: postgresql, polygon, postgis-2.0

Newbie to PostGIS/Postgres. I have the follow query which returns me 2 `GEOMETRYCOLLECTIONS`. Is there a way within my current query to return one polygon?

```
SELECT ST_AsText(ST_Collect(ST_Simplify(geom,.005))) AS singlegeom 
FROM public.mzones 
WHERE id = ALL(ARRAY['GMZ730']) 
UNION 
SELECT ST_AsText(ST_COLLECT(ST_Simplify(geom,.005))) AS singlegeom 
FROM counties 
WHERE fips IN (01031,01045,01061,01067,01069,12005,12013,12037,12039,12045,12059,12063,12073,12077,12129,12131,12133,13061,13087,13099,13201,13253)
;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a subquery and [ST_Union](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Union.html)

```
select ST_AsTexT(ST_Union(a.singlegeom, b.singlegeom ))
from (
    SELECT ST_COLLECT (ST_Simplify(geom ,. 005)) AS singlegeom
    FROM PUBLIC .mzones
    WHERE ID = ALL (ARRAY [ 'GMZ730' ])
) a,
(
SELECT ST_COLLECT (ST_Simplify(geom ,. 005))  AS singlegeom
FROM counties
WHERE fips IN (01031,01045,01061,01067,01069,12005,12013,12037,12039,12045,12059,12063,12073,12077,12129,12131,12133,13061,13087,13099,13201,13253)
) b
```

Comment: this is what I endedup with`code`$zonesearch=implode(',',$mzones);
 $txtsearch=implode(',',$ctyquery); 
$sqla="select ST_AsTexT(ST_Union(a.singlegeom, b.singlegeom ))
  from(  SELECT ST_UNION(ST_MakeValid (ST_Simplify(geom ,.055))) AS singlegeom
    FROM public.mzones
    WHERE ID = ALL (ARRAY [ '".$zonesearch."' ])
) a,
(
SELECT ST_UNION(ST_MakeValid (ST_Simplify(geom ,.055)))  AS singlegeom
FROM public.counties
WHERE fips IN (".$txtsearch.")
) b";

Comment: is is what I endedup with`$zonesearch=implode(',',$mzones);
 $txtsearch=implode(',',$ctyquery); 
$sqla="select ST_AsTexT(ST_Union(a.singlegeom, b.singlegeom ))
  from(  SELECT ST_UNION(ST_MakeValid (ST_Simplify(geom ,.055))) AS singlegeom
    FROM public.mzones
    WHERE ID = ALL (ARRAY [ '".$zonesearch."' ])
) a,
(
SELECT ST_UNION(ST_MakeValid (ST_Simplify(geom ,.055)))  AS singlegeom
FROM public.counties
WHERE fips IN (".$txtsearch.")
) b";`